# Run function for all file inputs types in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have several input type file in my page and want to run a function that gives me the size of the file.
I do have the function for getting the file type size, but I wonder if there´s a way I can call this same function to the other input type element.

The current way I have it, I will need to create a new function for it and don´t want that. 
This is my [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/fajawa/edit?html,js)

```
<input type="file" name="someName" id="uploadID" />
<input type="file" name="someName" id="uploadID2" />
<input type="file" name="someName" id="uploadID3" /> 

var el = document.getElementById('uploadID');
el.onchange = function(){
  var input, file;

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('uploadID');
    if (!input) {
        alert("p", "Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
        alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
        alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0]; console.log(file);
        alert( "File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the same function as an event listener of all inputs. You don't need to create a new one for each input because in an event listener you can reference the element to which the listener was added by using `this`.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input');
[].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', listener);
});
function listener() {
  if (!window.FileReader) {
    alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
    return;
  }
  var input = this;
  if (!input.files) {
    alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
  } else if (!input.files[0]) {
     alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
  } else {
     var file = input.files[0]; console.log(file);
     alert( "File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
  }
}
```